# Encoded/serialization Json syntax vs. decoded/deserialized Json syntax

Tags: php, syntax, android-emulator, json

I'm new to working with Json strings and am not really sure if the JsonTextDecode block on the AppInventor works correctly, because the input and the result seems the same to me...

So by the way, what exactly is correct? encode or serialize and decode or deserialize??

Here is the (supposedly) encoded Json string which I receive back from my database using php (did this with a little help from a colleague):

[{"pid":"1","name":"Jan","age":"2","gender":"male"}]

And here is the (supposedly) deserialized Json string which I receive on my Android emulator when using the Blocks editor tool:

[{"pid":"1","name":"Jan","age":"2","gender":"male"}]

So what's the difference?

And how should it be handled?

Can I extract the value of "name" which is "Jan" from the string and only display that?

I'll stop before I start asking too many questions, my main concern is to understand Json strings better.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a function in any language to handle json.

In PHP you can decode JSON string into array or object using `json_decode` function, Thus you can easily access the values.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the two strings look different? In the example I showed, the Json strings look the same before and after the decoding takes place. Shouldn't they differ?

Comment: They are same and there is not json decoding applied on them. They both are encoded. Try to decode them

Comment: According to me, that's what the AppInventor's JsonTextDecode block is supposed to do (http://www.appinventorbeta.com/learn/reference/components/other.html#Web). So I think that either I'm using it wrong, or I don't understand the whole concept at all... or the block is broken, which is probably not the case cause others have used it before as I found in the forum. Anyway. I'll keep trying. Thanks :)